# Laptop lid-open effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I **love** the way the MacBook opens on the WhitePage (http://whitepagehq.com) homepage. I'd like to create a similar effect.

Is this created using CSS Animation, JQuery, or both? I can't seem to figure out from the Inspector. Have you seen a similar animation somewhere else?

How can I make something like this for my website?

Comment: as others said, they simply change the height of the picture. a little fakey if you ask me, but since the lid is not opened fully, it doesn't matter. if you want to make an animation where the lid is fully opened have a look at css transform: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two images:

```
<img src="lib/img/laptop-closed.png" class="lid-closed"/>
<img src="lib/img/laptop-open.png?1" class="lid-open"/>
```

The animation simply involves changing the `laptop-open.png` image's height on document ready.

This is done using jQuery (within the main page from line 126):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.lid-closed').animate({
        top:10,
        height:9,
        width:840
    }, {
        easing:'linear',
        duration:500
    });

    $('.lid-open').animate({
        height:207
    }, {
        easing:'easeOutQuad',
        duration:1000
    });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

They are using jquery to animate the height of the open laptop image:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.lid-closed').animate({
        top: 10,
        height: 9,
        width: 840
    },
    {
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: 500
    });$('.lid-open').animate({
        height: 207
    },
    {
        easing: 'easeOutQuad',
        duration: 1000
    });
},
1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is done by jQuery.animate() method, you can find it in their inline js script. (View Source -> line 126). Basically they vary the height of the 'open' image at the same time as the 'closed' image. Open image expands and the closed part of the lid moves up.